# Fastest way to install a multisite?

Tags: installation, linux

I setted up a Ubuntu-Nginx VPS machine with phpmyadmin and WP-CLI. I'm ready to start working with WordPress.

What's the fastest way to install a multisite?

Maybe with WP-CLI, maybe there's a ready, remote, communal script I could run with `curl`?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way will be wp cli usage.

Look a few links. This might help you.

[multisite convert](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/core/multisite-convert/)

[multisite install](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/core/multisite-install/)

[small tutorial](https://tipstricks.itmatrix.eu/install-a-multisitewpmu-wordpress-with-wp_cli/)